# Unable to look up git (servname not supported)

Tags: git, vim

Running centos 7, vim [Plug Installer](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), I encounter clone issues with git:

```
:PlugInstall
  1 Updated. Elapsed time: 1.226362 sec.
  2 [===x==x===xx===x=xx=x===x=x=xxxxxx=xx]
  3
  4 - Finishing ... Done!
  5 - vim-slim: Already installed
  6 - vim-github-dashboard: Already installed
  7 - monokai: Already installed
  8 - fzf: Already installed
  9 - vim-json: Already installed
 10 - gocode: Already installed
 11 x delimitMate
 12     fatal: Unable to look up git (port :@github.com) (Servname not supported for ai_socktype)
 13     Cloning into '/root/.vim/plugged/delimitMate'...
```

`git clone git@github.com:Raimondi/delimitMate.git` works just fine, as does https endpoint -

suspecting dns, using nslookup returns the following:

```
› nslookup github.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   github.com
Address: 192.30.252.130
```

Why won't the plugin repos resolve?

Comment: `Unable to look up git (port :@github.com)` this suggests the clone URL is badly formatted (or badly parsed)

Comment: thanks. using full url like `Plug 'https://github.com/rorymckinley/vim-rubyhash.git'
` is another way to solve this issue as well, though its still curious that the shorthand path doesn't resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `git clone git@github.com:Raimondi/delimitMate.git` works just fine

In a terminal, but not with Plug.  According to the [Plug FAQ](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/faq#whats-the-deal-with-git-in-the-url) you're supposed to either use the `https` URLs, or, if you insist on using SSH URLs, set `g:plug_url_format` to `git@github.com:%s.git`.

Answer (score 0):

If the PlugInstall execute the git clone command as rot, using ssh, that means it will look for ssh keys (or ssh config file) in `/root`.

That would differ from your account, which should include all the ssh elements needed in `/home/<yourLogin>/.ssh`

Make sure to run everything with your account.